# Django: ModelForm and show data on the same url

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and trying to create my first app and I think I might need some little help :)

I have a ModelForm on a site to submit and want to show the data on the same page. I'm having trouble to set up two functions on the same page, I think i might have to use a class and set it in urls.py but I'm not able to make it work :( the code looks like this:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Eintrag

class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = Eintrag
            fields = ['Anmeldung', 'Essen']
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'form'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_name, name='form'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import NameForm
from .models import Eintrag

@login_required()
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            eintrag = form.save(commit=False)
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            eintrag.Name = request.user  # Set the user object here
            eintrag.pub_date = timezone.now()  # Set the user object here
            eintrag.save()

            return render(request, 'form/name.html', {'form': form})

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'form/name.html', {'form': form})

def post_list(request):
    posts = Eintrag.objects.all()
    return render('form/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

name.html

```
...
{% include "form/post_list.html" %}

<form action="/form/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...
```

post_list.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

So the problem is in urls.py only get_name is handled and I'm clueless how I should include post_list. I rather not want to use different url's, do I have to?

Thanks for any help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with [Class Based View] it would be better.
But with your `view`, you can send multiple data via `context`.

```
@login_required()
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        ''' codes '''
        eintrag.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path) # generate an empty form

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    posts = Eintrag.objects.all() # the queryset is here, and sent via context
    return render(request, 'form/name.html', {'form': form,'posts':posts})
```

I your html remain the same, but keep your form `action=''` empty

```
{% include "form/post_list.html" %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate URL or view for the list. Just include the queryset in the context of your `get_name` view.

```
posts = Eintrag.objects.all()
return render(request, 'form/name.html', {'form': form, 'posts': posts})
```